# How to stop or limit Google spreadsheet app script from running parallelly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, custom-function

I have a spreadsheet table like below.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | RJ162718 | `=FetchScript(A0)` |
| 1 | RJ258445 | `=FetchScript(A1)` |
| 2 | RJ228027 | `=FetchScript(A2)` |
| 3 | RJ258362 | `=FetchScript(A3)` |
| ... | ... | `=FetchScript(...)` |

The FetchScript function use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` to fetch a website where is not allow massive api calls.

How to stop script run parallelly or limit the number of executions at a time?

Thanks.

Edit:

Column A is part of url in `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`,
for example：

```
functtion FetchScript(ColunmA) {
url = "https://example.com/" + ColumnA;
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
//do something
}
```

Comment: By guessing your situation, I proposed a workaround. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your current situation:

Although I'm not sure about the detail of your function of `FetchScript`, when I saw your showing sample table, I guessed that your `FetchScript` might be as follows.

```
function FetchScript(value) {

  // do something.

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  // do something.

  return output;
}
```

#### Workaround:

In this case, when `=FetchScript(A1)`, `=FetchScript(A2)`,,, are put, each function is run with the asynchronous process. If you want to run the function with the synchronous process, how about the following modification?

```
function FetchScript(values) {
  var results = values.map(e => {
    // do something.

    var url = "###";
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

    // do something.

    return output; // In this case, please return 1 dimensional array for putting values to the row direction.
  });
  return results;
}
```

- In this case, please put a custom function like `=FetchScript(A1:A10)` to a cell. By this, the cell values are used in this modified function.
- In this modification, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is run with the synchronous process.
- If you want to run `UrlFetchApp.fetch` in the specific number, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function FetchScript(values) {
      var limit = 5; // Please set the number of run of UrlFetchApp.fetch. In this case, 5 values are used.

      var results = values.splice(0, limit).map(e => {
        // do something.

        var url = "###";
        var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

        // do something.

        return output; // In this case, please return a 1-dimensional array for putting values to the row direction.
      });
      return results;
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- From your question, I couldn't understand your actual script. So I proposed a sample script for explaining the method for achieving your goal using `// do something`. So, when you test this method, please reflect this in your actual script.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)